# AttributeError: type object 'Level' has no attribute 'platform_list'

Tags: python

I'm developing a platformer game for this I have tried to develop a level class however I keep on getting the error 'AttributeError: type object 'Level' has no attribute 'platform_list' I cannot identify the problem, I have taken some of the code which I feel is the area as to where the error triggers from is it possible to help?
'line 214, in  current_level.update(LVL)', 'line70,in update self.platform_list.update()'

```
    class Level(object):
        def __init__(self, Sprite):
            """ Constructor. Pass in a handle to player. Needed for when moving platforms
                collide with the player. """
            self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
            self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
            self.sprite = Sprite

            self.background = None

        def update(self):
            """ Update everything in this level."""
            self.platform_list.update()
            self.enemy_list.update()

        def draw(self, DS):
            """ Draw everything on this level. """

            # Draw all the sprite lists that we have


    self.platform_list.draw(DS)
        self.enemy_list.draw(DS)

LVL = Level
sprite = Sprite([400, 550])
level_list = []
level_list.append(Level_01)

# Set the current level
current_level_no = 0
current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprite.level = current_level

sprite.rect.x = 340
sprite.rect.y = H - sprite.rect.height
active_sprite_list.add(sprite)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

while not done:
    events()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key == [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            sprite.go_right()
        if key == [pygame.K_LEFT]:
            sprite.go_left()
        if key == [pygame.K_UP]:
            sprite.jump()
            # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
        if sprite.rect.right > W:
            sprite.rect.right = W

            # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
        if sprite.rect.left < 0:
            sprite.rect.left = 0

        current_level.draw(DS)
        active_sprite_list.draw(DS)
    # Call the `update` method of the sprite to move it.

    sprite.update()
    # Update the player.
    active_sprite_list.update()

    # Update items in the level
    current_level.update(LVL)

    DS.fill(BLACK)

    # Blit the sprite's image at the sprite's rect.topleft position.
    DS.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(FPS)
```

pygame.quit()

Comment: I'm confused. You call it as `current_level.update(LVL)`, but `update` doesn't take any arguments besides `self`, and `LVL` is just an alias for `Level`.

Comment: And where is `Level_01` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `LVL` is not what you think it is.
You should initialize it like this:

```
sprite = Sprite([400, 550])
LVL = Level(sprite)
level_list = [LVL]
```

then just call `current_level.update()`.
Also, I recommend changing the name `LVL` to `initial_level`. Much more meaningful.

Comment: Thank you and also ive defined level 01 as a class i didnt add it as i felt that wasnt the class that triggered the problem, it can now show the pygame window with the sprite however it doesnt do the movement shall i ask a new question or edit this question for more help?